# Method of taking an image with labels and turning it into a flash card

Tags: macos, automation, image-editing

I have a load of images (lots of them anatomy images, I am a medical student) and I want to turn them into flashcards. The part I am having trouble with is the modification of the image so that it hides the answers from me (in a logical way).

I have a whole load of images like this:

[image: Labeled AnatomyImage]
And I want to remove the text and replace it with numbers so it looks like this (the numbers are key):
[image]

How can I do this quickly? I do not need it to be automated just user friendly and quick (I have to be able to make these as I go through my courses). 
So far I have been thinking about covering the text with white rectangles and using some type of stamp tool that automatically incremented the number each time I clicked.

The problem is I am not sure what application to use and how to make such an automated stamp tool.

Any other ideas would be very welcome.

Really appreciate the help, 
Justin

Comment: How "key" are the numbers?  Given you are only asking one question on the flash card, a '?' next to the line of the feature you want named should be enough?

Comment: My reasoning behind the numbers is as follows: I want to minimize the amount of space used for storing media. If I can have one image that is referenced by 15 cards (as in the example above) I only need to store 1 image. Because of that I feel the numbering is pretty important.

Comment: Yeah I see.  Can your flash cards do multiple images?  If it can then you could keep the central part of the image the same, and just use a different image to the left or right showing which feature the card was after.  That image could be a thin strip with the question mark aligned.  If the flash cards support html, this could also be a single image with different top-margin to position it right.

Comment: I feel like that would ultimately take up a lot more work than the brute force method of using something like OSX preview.app with their annotation tools.

Comment: Ok cool. If you have found an approach, please add it as an answer if no one else comes up with anything.  Sounds like it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method could use an image-editing tool like the [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

You could prepare in advance rectangular images, each with its own consecutive number,
then paste them on top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not need automation, pick any drawing program that can draw rectangle and text, even MS Paint will work.

1. Open the image
2. Use `box tool` to draw 2 big white rectangles, one on each side of the image to cover all the words but not touching the picture in center.
3. Use `text tool` to start putting numbers by the end point of each line.

To make the process even quicker, memorize the "shortcut" to switch between 'box tool', 'text tool' and 'save as'.